# Can't charge or use my computer

Tags: power-supply, eee-pc, laptop-repair

I have a EEE pc.  It won't turn on.  The blue power light on the adaptor turns on but I'm unable to charge the computer.

Comment: Does the screen flicker/any lights at all go on?

Answer (score 1):

Without more details, I'd say the most likely bet is that your DC power connector is faulty. Did anything happen that may have damaged it (tripping over the cord, etc)? You might try to see if you can borrow a compatible power supply in order to verify that it is the Eee that is faulty and not the power adapter/power cable.

Answer (score 0):

There could be something going on with the battery. The electrical circuit goes through your battery and if that circuit is messed up for any reason, re-seating the battery could fix it. If this doesn't fix it, I would have to agree with @jcrawfordor.

I have had this issue with a Lenovo T510 at my work before. I simply turned the laptop off, took out the battery, placed the battery back in the laptop, and turned it back on. Everything was fine after that.